# Django - Store unescaped html in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to store raw, unescaped HTML inside one of my Django models for display on my home page. However, when I store it in a TextField it gets escaped, and ends up just being displayed as raw text. How can I store raw HTML in a Django model?

** EDIT **

It seems as if its not getting escaped in the model layer, but in the Template layer. Is there a special tag I should use? I checked the value in the shell and it's just fine, but for some reason when i did {{ block.html } (html is the attribute of the block object that stores the actual HTML) in the template, it comes out like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;This is a &lt;strong&gt;very&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;em&gt;important&lt;/em&gt; &lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;block&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot;padding-left: 30px;&quot;&gt;it has very significant content!&lt;/p&gt;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `safe` filter to present unescaped text, or `escape` filter to present escaped text. You can also use `autoescape` tag to set a block. (`{% autoescape on %}` or `{% autoescape off %}`)

Comment: Note the security implication of using `|safe` filter or when disabling autoescape. Make sure whatever passes through that filter/block is actually safe.