# saving html content as json in django db

Tags: python, html, json, django

I'm using DJango to save some html designs in my db. For example here 'Body' has some html content:

[image]

When I serialize the content into json, it seems like the html tags get eliminated:

```
from django.core import serializers

def list_templates(request):
    # retrieve all the templates from the DB
    all_templates = Template.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', all_templates))
```

Here is what I see:

[image]

Any recommendations on best practices for saving html codes and their serialization?

Comment: Possbile duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137736/django-store-unescaped-html-in-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would store your whole body in the DB but I'm using TinyMCE for storing and editing dynamic HTML. 
Here's the documentation: [readthedocs.io](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-the-widget)

Just do the following:

```
# Imports
from django.db import models
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

#models.py
class MyTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    describe = models.TextField(...)
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
```

This should give you the desired result without having to serialize data by yourself. You may have to include TinyMCE into your Django-Admin separately.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Django's ORM that seems me quite hasardous to store code straight as text. I would recommand you use a FileField to save directly the HTML (or whatever extension) file in your DB.

If you need to do it from a textarea input as in a form, read and write the content of the textarea in a .txt or .html file with Python open() function and then store it with a FileField.

Comment: May I know why this answer was down-voted and wont fit for you issue ?